# Readability CS50, pset2

Tags: c, cs50

When I run my code it is not giving me the correct grade, I do not understand why and I am really not sure where I have gone wrong or how I must fix it. Please if anyone can help me.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string ("Text: "); // asking for text input

   //counters set to zero
   int letters = 0;
   int words = 1;
   int sentances = 0;
       
   int n = strlen(text);
    
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // for counting letters words & sentances
     {
       if (isalpha (text[i]))
       {
         letters++;
       }
       else if (isspace (text [i]))
       {
         words++;
       }
       else if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?' )
       {
         sentances++;
       }
     }

    float l= 100 / letters * words;
    float s= 100 / sentances * words;
    float grade = (0.0588 * l) - (0.296 * s) - 15.8;

    grade = (round (grade));
    printf ("%i letters, %i words, %i sentances \n", letters, words, sentances);

    if (grade >= 1 && grade <= 16)
    {
      printf ("grade %i \n", (int) round (grade));
    }
    if (grade < 1)
    {
      printf ("Before grade 1\n");
    }
    if (grade > 16)
    {
      printf ("grade 16+\n");
    }
}
```

And when I check it everything shows before grade 1.

If i input this text : Would you like them here or there? I would not like them here or there. I would not like them anywhere.

The expected output would be: Grade 2

The actual output: Before grade 1

i hope this edit helps.

Comment: Single step through the program using your favourite debugger and watch the values of all variables.

Comment: This `100 / letters * words` looks wrong. At least you would want `100.0`

Comment: Please add: 1) The input string 2) The expected output 3) The actual output

Comment: Picking variable names such as `l` or `s`, and using values such as `(0.0588 * l) - (0.296 * s) - 15.8;` without any information saying what they are is cryptic and makes analyzing what you have written difficult.  Pick meaningful variable names, and avoid using magic numbers.

Comment: lundin thank you for your help i ran it though the de bugger everything works as it should code wise.

Comment: 4386427 i changed that formula and it still had the same out come. ill add the things you asked for i hope it it will help.

Comment: "Everything works as it should"  If that was true, you would get the output you want, which doesn't seem to be the case. Stepping through your code also includes checking correct values of your variables. Did you do that?

Comment: I changed the 100 to 100.0, I then changed the formula to 100 * L / word (same for sentances), removed   printf ("%i letters, %i words, %i sentances \n", letters, words, sentances); , I used this as a tool to help me figure out the problem, then I changed the capital letters on my other printf ‘s  printf ("grade %i \n", To printf (“Grade%i\n” as this was the requirement for cs50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
float l= 100 / letters * words;
float s= 100 / sentances * words;
```

and I think you have 2 problems.

**Problem 1**

Everything on the right hand side are integer. So the calculation will be done "in integers" and you'll get some unexpected roundings.

Use `100.0` to force floating point calculation.

**Problem 2**

Also I think the formulas are wrong. I think the correct form is:

```
float l= 100.0 * letters / words;   // average number of letters per 100 words
float s= 100.0 * sentances / words; // average number of sentences per 100 words
```

See [https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/readability/#:~:text=average%20number%20of%20sentences%20per%20100%20words](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/readability/#:%7E:text=average%20number%20of%20sentences%20per%20100%20words)

Comment: I have just switched the formula to yours you have solved my problem.Ii am so greatful! Thank you